# Why are the results of `turbn` and `turb2n` `NaN` in TraMineR `seqindic` function for every single sequence of the data?

Tags: sequence, nan, indicator, traminer

I am using TraMineR package to analyze sequence data. I have a large dataset of sequences, and I am trying to calculate the normalized turbulence using the `seqindic()` function in TraMineR.

However, when I run `seqindic()` on my data, the results of both `turbn` and `turb2n` are `NaN` for every single sequence in the data.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this issue and how to fix it? I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions. Thank you.

It's worth noting that the results of the function on several other indicators, including the standard deviations, were correctly calculated. So, how does it happen that normalized turbulence produces `NaN` values?

Comment: Please provide an sequence example and the alphabet. Could it be that the sequence length is shorter than the alphabet size?

Comment: This is the alphabet consisting of 25 states represented by the numbers: 0, 4, 16, 20, 32, 48, 52, 60, 84, 92, 116, 124, 126, 127, 252, 254, 255, 276, 348, 380, 476, 508, 509, 510, and 511.

An example: (126,27)-(124,16)-(60,30)-(52,17)-(0,73).

Answer (score 1):

The example you provide in the comment works fine. In the script below, we first transform the sequence data given in SPS format into STS format, then create the state sequence object using the alphabet argument to provide the full alphabet because only 5 of the 25 tokens of the alphabet occur in the sequence.

```
library(TraMineR)
alph <- c(0, 4, 16, 20, 32, 48, 52, 
          60, 84, 92, 116, 124, 126, 
          127, 252, 254, 255, 276, 348, 
          380, 476, 508, 509, 510, 511)
data.sps <-  "(126,27)-(124,16)-(60,30)-(52,17)-(0,73)"
data.sts <- seqformat(data.sps, from="SPS", to="STS")
s <- seqdef(data.sts, alphabet=alph)
seqindic(s, indic=c("turb", "turb2", "turbn", "turb2n"))

#         Turb      Turbn    Turb2     Turb2n
# [1] 8.186515 0.04436121 6.750483 0.03546431
```

---

*Edit*

However, when the number of susbsequences of the DSS exceeds the greatest double value allowed on your system (`.Machine$double.xmax`), the maximum possible value of the turbulence cannot be computed and, as a result, the normalization cannot be applied.

Comment: Thank you, Gilbert. I followed your approach and tested several other samples; all produced valid results. However, I also found some other samples resulting in NaN values. After comparing them, I realized that the issue seems to arise when the maximum sequence length exceeds 1000. To illustrate, consider the example sequence (510,405)-(254,1238):
Turb  Turbn  Turb2  Turb2n
3.956368  NaN  2.704095  NaN

Comment: You are right, there is an issue when the max sequence length exceeds some value. This occurs when the number of susbsequences of the DSS exceeds the greatest double value allowed on your system (`.Machine$double.xmax`). My suggestion is to use the complexity index instead of the turbulence.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. I can also use Turb2, which is not normalized.